# I have xpath written in Selenium RC & now I want to write the same xpath in selenium Webdriver. below is the xpath

Tags: xpath, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I have xpath written in Selenium RC & now I want to write the same xpath in selenium Webdriver. below is the xpath:

```
"//table[@id='lgnLogin']/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[4]/td"
```

by using this xpath, i am capturing the error message displayed on my application like "Please check your Password".

Now how can I write it in Webdriver. I have different ways but, not worked out.

`"String msg= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@td='error2']")).toString();"` - This is what i did in Webdriver.

Please help me out on this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XPath hadn't change from Selenium RC to WebDriver.

If you were able to use the some XPath-expression before it should work in WebDriver too (in 99% of cases as usual).

The code below should work but it's pretty hard to answer without seeing your HTML.

```
String msg= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='lgnLogin']/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[4]/td")).getText();
```

`//*[@td='error2']` - this expression looks bad as it means "any element with attribute named "td" and value "error2". I suppose that you don't have 'td' attributes in your HTML.

And to the end. I wouldn't recommend to use such long XPath expressions as in your example. It might be broken due to any minor change in layout. It's better to use some specific attributes rather than long hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion & will try to use as you said. Actually after switching to another window, i have not switched back to main window that caused the issue here. Now I am able to get the xpath message correctly and populated on the console. This issue can be closed now.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to start would be to start with the basics : http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#introducing-the-selenium-webdriver-api-by-example

What findElement would do is just locate the element that you want to interact with.  After you locate the element you need to perform the action that you want to do with the element.  In your case, you want the text inside the element.  So you can look at appropriate functions of the WebElement interface and use the appropriate method, in your case, getText.

Comment: In webdriver, there is no getText. we have get & getTitle

Comment: driver.findElement would return a webelement and not webdriver instance.  So you should be looking at webelement methods and not webdriver's.

Comment: I have used the getText as per u, but i am getting the same error. I am not able to identify the text displayed from the application using this xpath.